# Why does Prolog generate additional variables while querying?

Tags: prolog

Knowledge base:

```prolog
child(martha,charlotte).
child(charlotte,caroline).
child(caroline,laura).
child(laura,rose).


descend(X,Y) :- child(X,Y).
descend(X,Y) :- child(X,Z),
                descend(Z,Y).
```

Query: `descend(martha, laura).`

Prolog first calls child(martha, laura) which fails and then returns to descend(martha, laura).

Now, it needs to call child(martha, Z) to check the conditions but why does it need to give Z to another variable like `_2978`? I think it would have been fine to just call (or query) child(martha, Z).

Trace:

```prolog
   Call: (8) descend(martha, laura) ? creep
   Call: (9) child(martha, laura) ? creep
   Fail: (9) child(martha, laura) ? creep
   Redo: (8) descend(martha, laura) ? creep
   Call: (9) child(martha, _2978) ? creep   % HERE, why does Prolog 
                                            % need this extra variable                                             
                                            % _2978 instead of 
                                            % utilizing the original Z variable? 
   Exit: (9) child(martha, charlotte) ? creep
```

A simpler example:
I have the knowledge base: `numeral(0)`

Then I query `numeral(X)`. During the trace I can see that the first call is to `numeral(_3233)`.

Comment: Do you know the difference between mutable variables and immutable variables? Do you know what bound and unbound means? When you know the answers to these questions you will be much closer to answering your question.

Comment: @GuyCoder Could you link me to some good reference for these in Prolog please? My book doesn't cover them and I couldn't find a good reference online. Although I do know about mutability in the context of other languages.

Comment: `Could you link me to some good reference for these in Prolog please? ` I don't know of any for Prolog off the top of my head. I learned about the terms when learning functional languages like ML, OCaml and F#.

Comment: How would you handle recursion if every instance used the same variable names?

Comment: `My book` Which book? Is this for a school class? If so ask the teacher about the terms. Also if you know an Object-Oriented programming language already then do yourself a favor and forget all of it when learning Prolog; the baggage from O-O languages will only make learning Prolog much harder.

Comment: @GuyCoder Forgetting OO is hard when I am also learning Java for another course in my uni lol.

Comment: `Forgetting OO is hard when I am also learning Java for another course in my uni lol.` I had a similar problem when taking COBOL and PL/1 at the same time. COBOL end statements with a period and PL/1 ends statements with a semicolon. Needless to say I quickly learned to change hats.

Comment: I checked the O'Keefe book and in there the word to use is `instantiated` (think bound). So when searching for the term bound with Prolog instead use `instantiated` and you get better hits. Thus: [A Concise Introduction to Prolog](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/Concise%20Guides/Concise%20Prolog.html). It still does not go into enough detail for a beginner but it does use Prolog and is better than nothing.

Comment: I hate to say it but the best way to probably understand this for a beginner is to have someone step through the logic of Prolog as it solves a simple query and use the terms  `bound`, `immutable`, `free`, etc. while doing each step. Also many of the articles, blogs, videos, etc. are not noting that a new variable with the same name is available when the code starts a new goal. This can be seen by seeing what happens in the stack.  In other words, you are paying the teacher so make them earn their pay.

Comment: Why did someone give this a close vote for seeking a recommendation. Where is the request for a recommendation in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Internally Prolog engine doesn’t use variable names, variables are just addresses of special kind cells in memory. So when it needs to represent a term during tracing it has to reconstruct its textual representation, and as there is no names it generates them in a unified way for all variables just by numbering them in an ascending order. You might ask why it doesn’t preserve names as metadata — the answer is that it can do that but it doesn’t make a sense since due to possible recursion it will need create a ‘copy’ of same var and again we come to necessity of generic naming.

Comment: it _could_ conceivably use names like `_Z_2978`. "due to possible recursion it will need to create a ‘copy’ of same var" is indeed the answer.

Comment: There is no guarantee that variables are numbered in ascending order. However, the names should be unique.